# Automapper multiple memberOptions

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a ViewModel that needs data from 2 collections. The 2 collections are members of `Indicatiestelling`. So to map this I pass an instance of `Indicatiestelling`.

Each property uses a ValueResolver that gets the right value out of the given collection. To make this work I need to register the ValueResolver for each property and the source for each property. I tried to do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Indicatiestelling, ClientRechtmatigheidDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.HasFactBeoordelenRechtmatigheid, (opt) => { opt.ResolveUsing<IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver>(); opt.MapFrom(src => src.IndicatiestellingFacts); })
                .ForMember(dest => dest.HasFactRechtmatig, (opt) => { opt.ResolveUsing<IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver>(); opt.MapFrom(src => src.IndicatiestellingFacts); })
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SoortVoorziening, (opt) => { opt.ResolveUsing<IndicatiestellingAnswerValueResolver>(); opt.MapFrom(src => src.IndicatiestellingAnswer); })
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ZZP, (opt) => { opt.ResolveUsing<IndicatiestellingAnswerValueResolver>(); opt.MapFrom(src => src.IndicatiestellingAnswer); });
```

This code doesn't work, I still get mapping errors:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: HashSet`1 -> Boolean

I searched for an example/docs about using multiple member options, nothing came up. Is it supported? And ifso, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think they can be combined in the way you want, but with a little refactoring you can use this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Indicatiestelling, ClientRechtmatigheidDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HasFactBeoordelenRechtmatigheid, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver.Resolve(src.IndicatiestellingFacts)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HasFactRechtmatig, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver.Resolve(src.IndicatiestellingFacts)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SoortVoorziening, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => IndicatiestellingAnswerValueResolver.Resolve(src.IndicatiestellingAnswer)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ZZP, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => IndicatiestellingAnswerValueResolver.Resolve(src.IndicatiestellingAnswer)));
```

(I refactored your `IValueResolver`s into `static` methods)

Or you can make your `IValueResolver`s know which member to look at, e.g. hardcoded:

```
public class IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var model = (Model.Indicatiestelling)source.Value;
        var obj = model.IndicatiestellingFacts;
        // calculate with obj
    }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Indicatiestelling, ClientRechtmatigheidDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HasFactBeoordelenRechtmatigheid, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver<Model.Indicatiestelling>>())
    // etc
```

Or using a `Func`:

```
public class IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver<TSource> : IValueResolver
{
    private Func<TSource, object> selector;
    public IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver(Func<TSource, object> selector)
    {
        this.selector = selector;
    }
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var model = (TSource)source.Value;
        object obj = selector(model);
        // calculate with obj
    }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Model.Indicatiestelling, ClientRechtmatigheidDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.HasFactBeoordelenRechtmatigheid,
    opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver<Model.Indicatiestelling>>()
                .ConstructedBy(() => new IndicatiestellingFactValueResolver<Model.Indicatiestelling>(x => x.IndicatiestellingFacts)))
    // etc
```